# Ionic 2/3, data keep in cache device when database is update

Tags: angular, http, caching, ionic-framework, device

i have a couple of variables declared in the controller ("date" and "clientes" ). They are updated through http and show them with ngModel. But every time I update some data in the database, this data is not updated in the device until I delete the cache of the application. Why is this happening? Is there any way to remove the cache from Ionic?

PS: I’m not using Storage or LocalStorage.

```
export class HomePage {
public date: string;
public clientes = [];

 constructor(private device: Device, private http: Http, public navCtrl: 
 NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController, public menu: 
 MenuController) {
   this.menu = menu;
   this.menu.enable(true, 'myMenu');

   this.http.get('http://fixingmexico.com/prapi/fecha').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.date = data;
   });
   this.http.get('http://fixingmexico.com/prapi/agenda').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.clientes = data;
   });
 }
}
```